# Javadoc links to current method implementation, is it possible?

Tags: java

I use Javadoc to generate Html doc, but I can not find any document how to link to current method implementation.
E.g.

```
class MyClass{
public void fun(){}
}
```

I want to see the implementation of method in the Javadoc when I click on the fun.

Comment: Do you mean you want to link to the method's source code?

Comment: Yep, the implementation of method.

Comment: From what I am aware, this is not a feature supported directly in Javadoc.

Comment: Where do you want to see the implementation?
Do you want to see the javadoc as mouseover (e.g. in eclipse), click on the linked method and jump to the implementation? In that case, just use `@see MyClass#fun()` or `{@link MyClass#fun()}` (works for IntelliJ IDEA also)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported by Javadoc. For this to work, you'd need a web server with the sources and a standardized format how to link to source files. Also, you'd need a way to identify the code block in the source. Line numbers would be brittle.

Most people create source JARs and attach them to the normal JARs on the classpath in the IDE. The IDE can then do this trick.